# I have installed Jenkins but I am unable to connect to the port 8080

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, installation

I have installed Jenkins but  I am unable to connect to port 8080.
Java is installed.Jenkins installation says it's fully up and running and I have the initial password. But I am getting errors as "localhost refused to connect".

Comment: Can you add some information like which operating system you are on, which packages you installed and how you are trying to reach the application?

Comment: Can you post your log

Comment: Do you use `http` or `https`? What if you try the other? What if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: I tried another port and it worked. Thank you